# Global duality theorem for 2-part

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves, duality, galois-cohomology

$\DeclareMathOperator\coker{coker}\DeclareMathOperator\Sha{Sha}$Let $K$ be a number field.
Let $E/K$ be an elliptic curve over $K$.
Suppose finiteness of $\Sha(E/K)$.

According to Global duality theorem (cf. J.S Milne, Arithmetic duality theorems, 6.14(b)
https://www.jmilne.org/math/Books/ADTnot.pdf)

states

$$0\to \Sha(E/K)\to H^1(G_K,E)\to \bigoplus_{v\in M_K}H^1(G_{K_v},E)\to \widehat{E(K)}^*\to 0$$ is an exact sequence,
where $\widehat{E(K)}$ is a completion with respect to finite index subgroups, and  $*$ is Pontryagin dual.

My question is, are there known result for $Sha(E/K)[2]$ ?

$$0\to \Sha(E/K)[2]\to H^1(G_K,E)[2]\to \bigoplus_{v\in M_K}H^1(G_{K_v},E)[2]\to X\to 0:\text{exact}$$

In other words, can we find $X$ in explicit form like in the above sequence ?

It is ok to exchange  $H^1(G_K,E)[2]$ and  $\bigoplus_{v\in M_K}H^1(G_{K_v},E)$ to some appropriate other groups.

Comment: If $0$, $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, $0$ are six terms in an exact sequence of abelian groups, then $0\to A[2]\to B[2]\to C[2]\to D[2]\to 0$ and $0\to A/2A \to B/2A \to C/2C \to D/2D\to 0$ are two complexes with the same cohomology but shifted by 2.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich Is that via a spectral sequence argument? I can see how that one works, I'm just curious if you had another way

Comment: If $f\colon U^{\bullet} \to V^{\bullet}$ is a morphism of exact sequences, the long exact sequence gives that the cohomolgy of the kernel complex $\ker f^{\bullet}$ is shifted by one of the cohomology of the image complex $\operatorname{im} f^{\bullet}$, which is then one more shifted from the cokernel complex $\operatorname{coker} f^{\bullet}$.

Comment: @Chris Wuthrich  I confirmed that $? \cong \widehat{E(K)}^*$($?$ is $\text{coker}(H^1(G_K,E)[2]\to \bigoplus_{v\in M_K}H^1(G_{K_v},E)[2])$ in my question)

Comment: @Brian Shin. I confirmed that $? \cong \widehat{E(K)}^*$. This also follows from J.S.Milne's 'Arithmetic duality theorems', p83.

Comment: @Duality I doubt this is right. $\widehat{E(K)}^*$ will have elements of all finite orders if the rank is positive, but your cokernel should be $2$-torsion.

Comment: @Chris Wuthrich, you are correct. But I’m confused. If $S$ is all finite places of $K$, Milne’s exact sequence in p83(https://www.jmilne.org/math/Books/ADTnot.pdf)  states 2-part version is exact because 2 is of course $S$ unit. The ground field is general global field.

Comment: In the book $(m)$ in there is the $m$-primary, not $m$-torsion part and ${}^{\wedge}$ is the $m$-adic completion. (Though this book is known to have errors, so check what you are doing. Probably cohomology of number fields is the better source for this.)

Comment: Dear @Chris Wuthrich, I utilized the Snake Lemma and proved that the '?' in my question represents a finite group, with its order being less than $\#山(E/K)[2] \#E(K)[2] \times 2^{\text{rank}(E/K)}$.Do you think this estimate can be further improved?

Comment: @Duality I don't know. Your expression is the size of the 2-Selmer group. I would go back to the global duality for the finite $E[2]$. That seems easier than to work from the limit version.

Comment: Dear @Chris Wuthrich, thank you very much. Could you tell me what the statement of 'global duality for the finite E[2]' is? Also, if there are any references you could suggest, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @Chris Wuthrich I found the answer of this question in  'Arithmetic of curves of genus 1' ( https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN243919689_0216?tify=%7B%22view%22:%22info%22,%22pages%22:%5B154%5D%7D ).          'X'  in my question is denoted by ж there, and its order is exactly equal to $\text{Sel}^2(E/K)$.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's generally recommended to answer one's own questions, but I will leave my final comment with Professor Chris Wuthrich as an answer. I might be making a mistake, so I would greatly appreciate it if you could point out any errors through comments or edits.

I found the answer of this question in  'Arithmetic of curves of genus 1' ( https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN243919689_0216?tify=%7B%22view%22:%22info%22,%22pages%22:%5B154%5D%7D ).          'X'  in this question is denoted by ж there, and its order is exactly equal to $\text{Sel}^2(E/K)$.
There, exact sequence in this question
$$0\to \text{Sha}(E/K)[2]\to H^1(G_K,E)[2]\to \bigoplus_{v\in M_K}H^1(G_{K_v},E)[2]\to ж\to 0$$ is used to prove

$$0\to \text{Sha}(E/K)\to H^1(G_K,E)\to \bigoplus_{v\in M_K}H^1(G_{K_v},E)\to \widehat{E(K)^*}\to 0$$.

I tried to prove the sequence below deduces the one above.
Indeed , there is a natural surjection $ж\to \widehat{E(K)^*}[2]$ and diagram chase proves $\#ж\le \text{Sel}^2(E/K)$.
However I put the cart behind the horse because above one proves the below.